# FTP multiple files using apache commons into a local directory

Tags: java, apache, ftp-client

I am trying to download All files in a directory to my local machine using apache commons like this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class FTPExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect("MyHostName");
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.login("username", "password");
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles("/App/");
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Ftp Files/"  + file.getName());
            client.retrieveFile(file.getName(),fos);             
        }
    }
}
```

Am able to list the Files in the Directory but I am Getting FilenotFound Exception when trying to Download the files. Please help.
My Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Ftp Files\01 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at ftpexample.FTPExample.main(FTPExample.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

**EDIT: I need the files to be stored in the Folder Ftp File/ in their original file names.**

Comment: It seems that the folder on the local machine does not exist.

Comment: No it is there Trust Me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you to those who tried to help. I found the answer to my problem here. this is How I did it:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;


public class FTPExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            //new ftp client
            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
            //try to connect
            ftp.connect("MyHhostName");
            //login to server
            if (!ftp.login("username", "password")) {
                ftp.logout();
            }
            int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
            //FTPReply stores a set of constants for FTP reply codes. 
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftp.disconnect();
            }

            //enter passive mode
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            //get system name
            System.out.println("Remote system is " + ftp.getSystemType());
            //change current directory
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/App/PMIGENV/BACK/Finacle/FC/app/CDCI_LOGS/log/UBSADMIN");
            System.out.println("Current directory is " + ftp.printWorkingDirectory());

            //get list of filenames
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();

            if (ftpFiles != null && ftpFiles.length > 0) {
                //loop thru files
                for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {
                    if (!file.isFile()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println("File is " + file.getName());
                    //get output stream
                    OutputStream output;
                    output = new FileOutputStream("FtpFiles" + "/" + file.getName());
                    //get the file from the remote system
                    ftp.retrieveFile(file.getName(), output);
                    //close output stream
                    output.close();

                    //delete the file
                    // ftp.deleteFile(file.getName());

                }
            }

            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Working Code . i Have been trying it for a long time but now it's working fine.
Previously it was downloading files with 0Kb size.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;  
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;


public class FTPDownload {

public void ftpDownload() throws IOException
{
    String host="your_host_name";
    String uname="your_user_name";
    String pass="your_password";
    String remoteDIR="/public_html/tmp";
    String localDIR="D://FTP";

    //Object for FTPClient class

    FTPClient ftp=new FTPClient();  

    ftp.connect(host);
    boolean login=ftp.login(uname, pass);
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteDIR);
    FTPFile[] files=ftp.listFiles();


    try{
            if(login){
        System.out.println("Your Are Logged In "+ftp.getStatus()); 
        System.out.println("Working Directory is "+ftp.printWorkingDirectory());
        System.out.println("Local Directory is "+localDIR);
        System.out.println("Total Files Are "+files.length);


        if(files != null && files.length >0 )
        {
            for(FTPFile fl:files)
            {
                if(!fl.isFile())
                {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(fl.getName());
                OutputStream out;
                out=new FileOutputStream(localDIR+"/"+fl.getName());
                ftp.retrieveFile(fl.getName(), out);
                out.close();
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry");
    }

    ftp.logout();
    ftp.disconnect();

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FTPDownload ft=new FTPDownload();
    ft.ftpDownload();
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it is a bit too late for this?

Comment: i know that but i just wanted to share Whatever i did , i thought it may help someone like me who really wants to solve the same problem .

Comment: 2022 and still  usefull, legacy code is everywhere